# integrate devise_invitable with angular js in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise-invitable

As the question I ask, now I can easily use devise_invitable module in rails app. However, it is hard to migrate to angular js.
I'm trying to use $http.post with url '/users/invitation.json' to trigger the invitation on the server side.

```
$scope.inviteUser = ->
  $http.post('/users/invitation.json',
    email: $scope.email
).success (data) ->
  _log "successful"
```

The log file shows that

```
Started POST "/users/invitation.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-24 03:48:49 +1100
Processing by Devise::InvitationsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"email"=>"sample@mail.com", "invitation"=>{"email"=>"sample@mail.com"}}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id"      ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 3ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

I can figure out that the problem could be the credential. The params apparently miss

```
"authenticity_token"=>"MEAh9r7vD8cUxXQH9+qnjykHKV8OeC+fvuNW6Whsewg="
```

But don't know how to fix it. In plain rails app, every thing goes well. I can post email to user_invitation_path to invite new user.
And I'm really new to angular js, could any one help me on it?

Answer (score 1):

I figure out what wrong with my code after several hours. There are 2 problems in the code. Firstly, I should add csrf manually, which should be

```
myAngularApp.config([
  "$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
}
```

or just one simpler approach is use a gem

```
# Gemfile
gem 'angular_rails_csrf'
```

Secondly, in console, I can use User.invite!(:email => "123@example.com") to send the invitation, that because the email has been wrapped as an attribute in a User object. So in $http request, we cannot directly use email as a parameter.

```
  $scope.inviteUser = ->
    user = {
      email: $scope.email
    }
    $http.post('/users/invitation',
      user: user
    )
```

Finally everything works well!!